# Экранирование кавычек при выполнении команды на удалённом ssh сервере

Tags: linux, bash

Хочу прочитать из локального файла id'шники и сформировать команду curl которую запустить на удалённом сервере:

```
#!/bin/bash

myHeader1="myHeader1"
runAtServer="ssh -l '//user:ak//configuration_id:production#asdf' serverAddr"

while IFS= read -r line
do
    commandTemplate="curl --location --request POST 'http://server.ru/order/add?id=$line' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'MyHdr: $myHeader1' -i"
    cmd="$runAtServer '$commandTemplate'"
    
    #eval $cmd

    echo $cmd
    echo ""
    sleep 0.25
done < source_file.csv
```

И через echo отображается как надо:

```
ssh -l '//user:ak//configuration_id:production#asdf' serverAddr 'curl --location --request POST 'http://server.ru/order/add?id=85450438' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'MyHdr: myHeader1' -i'

ssh -l '//user:ak//configuration_id:production#asdf' serverAddr 'curl --location --request POST 'http://server.ru/order/add?id=83555429' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'MyHdr: myHeader1' -i'

ssh -l '//user:ak//configuration_id:production#asdf' serverAddr 'curl --location --request POST 'http://server.ru/order/add?id=85825033' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'MyHdr: myHeader1' -i'
```

А вот когда запускаешь команду - выдаёт ошибку:

```
./test.sh: line 15: application/json --header MyHdr:: No such file or directory
```

Как подобрать правильные кавычки, чтобы и значения переменных ушли на сервер и чтобы curl команда со всеми параметрами ушла на удалённый сервер как надо?

Пробовал избавляться от переменной commandTemplate:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    eval $runAtServer "curl --location --request POST 'http://server.ru/order/add?id=$line' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'MyHdr: $myHeader1' -i"
done < source_file.csv
```

Не работает, хоть без кавычек вокруг curl, хоть в одинарных, хоть в двойных.

Comment: как минимум, я бы `eval` убрал — он тоже один уровень кавычек раскрывает… ну а дальше мучительная, скурпулёзная отладка…

Comment: @Fat-Zer Вот к тому же иду: скрипты подобные нужны часто, но проще всё-таки не плодить аккуратно переменные а писать как есть.

Comment: Можно пример файла? А то я увидел слова `json` и `csv` и прям стало интересно.

Comment: `ssh -e ...` не помогает?

Answer (score 3):

Дабы отделаться минимальной кровью я бы делал всё это как-то так:

```
#!/bin/bash

myHeader1="myHeader1"
runAtServer=( ssh -l '//user:ak//configuration_id:production#asdf'
              serverAddr
            )

while IFS= read -r line
do
    
    commandTemplate=( curl "http://server.ru/order/add?id=$line" )
    commandTemplate+=( --request POST )
    commandTemplate+=( --header 'Content-Type: application/json' )
    commandTemplate+=( --header "MyHdr: $myHeader1"              )
    commandTemplate+=( --include  )
    commandTemplate+=( --location )

    "${runAtServer[@]}" "$(printf "%q " "${commandTemplate[@]}")"

    echo ""
    sleep 0.25
done < source_file.csv
```

Основные идеи:

- Избавиться от `eval`'а
- Использовать массивы для построения команд (`[@]` позволяет раскрывать их так чтобы каждый элемент становился отдельной строкой)
- Использовать `printf %q` для эскейпа строки для оболочки на удалённой машине (нужен GNU'тый `printf`)

Comment: А в чем преимущество именно массива? Почему бы просто строку не собрать таким же образом?

Comment: @ipatev_nn, в строке при её раскрытии каждый пробел будет отделять аргумент независимо от кавычек, т.е. если, например, собрать строку `FOO="foo 'bar baz'"`, то при запуске `$FOO arg` она запустится как `foo "'bar" "baz'" arg`, а с массивом `FOO=(foo 'bar baz')` будет `"${FOO[@]}" arg` -> `foo 'bar baz' arg`